# A bag contains 5 white balls and 3 black balls. Another bag contains 4 white balls and 5 black balls.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

> A bag contains 5 white balls and 3 black balls. Another bag contains 4 white balls and 5 black balls. From any one of these bags, a single draw of two balls is made. Find the probability that one of them would be black and the other white.

As the total number of balls is $17$, the total number of cases of picking 2 balls will be $\binom{17}{2}$. To get the number of favourable cases, we consider the following:
Case 1: If the first bag is picked, the number of ways to pick one white and one black ball is $\binom{5}{1}\times\binom{3}{1}$.
Case 2: If the second bag is picked, the number of ways to pick one white and one black ball is $\binom{4}{1}\times\binom{5}{1}$.

The probability is then ratio of the number of favourable cases to the total number of cases, which is $\dfrac{\binom{5}{1}\times\binom{3}{1}+\binom{4}{1}\times\binom{5}{1}} {\binom{17}{2}}$.

Could anyone please tell me why this is wrong?

Comment: Because you aren't choosing two balls from the list of $17$, you are choosing a bag and then drawing two balls from that.

Comment: Yes, if the second bag had exactly two balls of one color, then the odds of both being that color would be at least $\frac12,$ no matter the composition of the first bag. This assumes you choose each bag with probability $\frac12.$

Comment: The $\binom{17}{2}$ different cases are not equally likely. Indeed, if the pair of balls are not in the same bag, the probability of getting that pair is $0.$

Comment: @lulu I got my error. So, will it be [5c1 * 3c1] / 8c2 + [4c1 * 5c1] / 9c2?

Comment: Except that you need to multiply it by $1/2$

Comment: Last comment good, except that you also have to apply the $(1/2)$ factor.  That is, probability of $(1/2)$ to be drawing from bag-1, and probability of $(1/2)$ to be drawing from bag-2.

Comment: @LakshayKhanna  As others have remarked, you need to multiply by $\frac 12$...trusting that there is an equal chance of picking either bag (which you did not specify but which I imagine you intended).